How to de-duplicate a variable's substring values?
Suppose I have a variable containing reported languages a respondent is fluent in. How might I remove duplicate sub-strings to create a new variable like so?
Languages                                 | Cleaned languages
------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
Sylvan Elvish-Westron-Sylvan Elvish       | Sylvan Elvish-Westron
Westron                                   | Westron
Khuzdul                                   | Khudzul
Quenyan Elvish-Sylvan Elvish              | Quenyan Elvish-Sylvan Elvish
Black Speech-Westron                      | Black Speech-Westron
Haradi-Haradi                             | Haradi

Assume I have a dictionary of 7,000+ possible language values.
I could imagine matching each of those languages to the first column, and populate the second column on positive hit, but is there a computationally cheaper way to do this?
Edit: This is a question about Stata.

What language? What have you tried so far?

@chepner This is about Stata.

@chepner Nick Cox is corrct about Stata! That's why the [stata] tag.

If we split the languages variable, we are safe taking the first language as the start of a new variable.
Then we loop over the other languages, adding them to the list so far if and only if they haven't been seen before.
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str35 languages str28 cleaned
"Sylvan Elvish-Westron-Sylvan Elvish" "Sylvan Elvish-Westron"       
"Westron"                             "Westron"                     
"Khuzdul"                             "Khudzul"                     
"Quenyan Elvish-Sylvan Elvish"        "Quenyan Elvish-Sylvan Elvish"
"Black Speech-Westron"                "Black Speech-Westron"        
"Haradi-Haradi"                       "Haradi"                      
end

split languages, parse(-)
local count = wordcount("`r(varlist)'")

gen wanted = languages1 

forval j = 2/`count' { 
    replace wanted = wanted + "-" + languages`j' if !strpos(wanted, languages`j')
}

list 

